# SKTileMapNode disappears when off-camera, does not reappear

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode, skcameranode

I have a SpriteKit platformer that uses a tile map for a background. The background in question is positioned 1 screen-height above the main content (it's positioned off-screen), acting as a forest canopy above the player. I accomplish that programmatically, like this:

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let columns = 20
let rows = 1
let tileSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

let container = SKSpriteNode()
let tileDefinition = SKTileDefinition(texture: MainData.textureAtlas.textureNamed("someTexture"), size: CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
let tileGroup = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: tileDefinition)
let tileSet = SKTileSet(tileGroups: [tileGroup])
let layer = SKTileMapNode(tileSet: tileSet, columns: columns, rows: rows, tileSize: tileSize)

container.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth*0.5, y: screenHeight*1.5)
container.size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(columns)*screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
container.zPosition = 3.0

layer.fill(with: tileGroup)
                
container.addChild(layer)
addChild(container)
```

A camera node follows the player.

**The problem:** If the player jumps up, the `SKTileMapNode` disappears when he comes back down. It never reappears. Its parent node, `container`, remains visible, so I think the problem is with the `SKTileMapNode`, not the `container`.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried the following, with numbers 2-5 being checked for the `SKTileMapNode`:

1. Setting `view.shouldCullNonVisibleNodes = false`.
2. Checking the `alpha` value. It's always `1.0`.
3. Checking the `position`. It's always `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)`.
4. Checking the `anchorPoint`. It's always `CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)`.
5. Checking the `zPosition`. It does not change, and there are no other nodes that could be obscuring the `SKTileMapNode` or its parent. Setting a higher value has no effect on the problem.
6. Checking that `container` remains visible. It does.

**On culling:**
It seems like the problem should be related to culling, but setting `view.shouldCullNonVisibleNodes=false` has no effect on the situation. I also checked to make sure the `SKTileMapNode` is always present as a child node of `container`. It is. I suppose this means that the node is *not* being culled. However, if I position `container` so that it's always *on*-screen, the problem does not occur at all; the `SKTileMapNode` remains visible. This leaves me very confused because it seems like these are conflicting facts.

**On devices:**
Using the simulator, at least, the problem does *not* occur on the older-style iPhones such as the SE and the iPhone 8. It
only happens on the newer iPhones, such as the iPhone 11 and iPhone
12. Having access to an iPhone 11, I can confirm that the problem is occurring on real devices, too.

**Question:** Why is my `SKTileMapNode` disappearing when off-camera (even with culling disabled)? How can I keep this node visible?

Thank you!

Comment: Why does `container.addChild(layer5)` show `layer5`? Should it not be `layer`?

Comment: @JohnL Oops. I edited the question to only include `layer`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I think you should use `showsNodeCount`, when the player jumps and comes back down if what you are saying is true, the number should decrease. Repeat with different simulator devices. Maybe also change the camera xscale and yscale in didMoveTo (so it is zoomed out more), to see where the tilenode goes when you jump.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just checked the node count. It does *NOT* decrease when the `SKTileMapNode` disappears, which is interesting. I also tried changing the camera's scale so the content appears zoomed out, which caused the problem to *NOT* occur (presumably because the node never goes off screen). However, I already know the `SKTileMapNode` doesn't *move* anywhere because I've checked its `position` and `anchorPoint` before and after the player jumps. Those values remain unchanged, as I mentioned in point #3 and #4. The lack of movement is confirmed by the zoomed-out check I did.

Comment: Ok. Im sure the tilenode is still there somewhere. What is `layer.zposition`? (I can see only container). I guess you could do `print(container.children)` in update, to really make sure it is there somewhere after you jump.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, because you have the container starting position 1.5xscreenheight, the container will not be a fixed e.g. 500 points above and outside of the screen view across ALL devives, its actual y position will be much higher up the larger the size of the screenheight. This may come into play if you use skactions to move a fixed amount, whereas your container position is variable.

Comment: `layer.zPosition` remains at 0 the whole time. I've tried setting it to something higher, like 5.0, but it didn't change the node's behavior. I tried `print(container.children)`. `layer` remains present as a child of `container`, so I guess that means it's not being culled. Here's what it prints: `Optional([<SKTileMapNode> name:'Default Tile Map' position:{0, 0} scale:{1.00, 1.00} accumulatedFrame:{{-8960, -207}, {17920, 414}}])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I've solved the problem.

I'm presenting my scene via SwiftUI `SpriteView`, which I had configured to allow background transparency, like this:

```
SpriteView(scene: theScene, options: [.allowsTransparency])
```

Removing the transparency option solved the problem:

```
SpriteView(scene: theScene)
```

Now, why should this be the case? I have no idea.

Comment: It's the case because default parameter for `options` is `[.shouldCullNonVisibleNodes]`.
So if you add `.shouldCullNonVisibleNodes` to your options it should work as well (`SpriteView(scene: theScene, options: [.allowsTransparency, .shouldCullNonVisibleNodes])`).
Please edit your answer if you have a chance, to let others better understand the solution.